# load and play another song when button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio

I'm trying to make a music player with React.js

The main component is a table container that holds the data about the songs (name, artist, duration). Each row of the table has a play/pause button.

I have another component to actually play the songs with the following code

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import './styles.css';


class BottomBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            play: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <audio controls controlsList='nodownload' autoPlay className='container'>
                <source src={this.props.songs.url} type='audio/mpeg'></source>
            </audio>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { ...state };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BottomBar);
```

And here is where that component is being rendered...

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from './containers/table';
import Bottombar from './containers/bottombar';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Table />
        { this.props.songs.currentPlaying ? <Bottombar /> : null }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { ...state };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

The url to the song gets updated when the play button gets pressed. However, how can I stop the old song from playing and start the new one? Right now if one song is playing and the user wants to play another song, he/she has to first pause the current song and then click on the play button for the new song...however, I want to be able to stop the current song from being played when the user presses the play button of another song and switch the audio to that song being played (this.props.songs.currentSong refers to the current song playing and will be undefined if there is no song playing).

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution to stop any other audio objects from playing is to do the following:

```
function stopAnyCurrentlyPlayingAudio() {

    for(const audio of document.querySelectorAll('audio')) {
        audio.pause()
        // audio.currentTime = 0; // Do this to reset play head, simulate "stop"
    }
}
```

You could technically use/call this function from anywhere in your application to stop currently playing audio.

#### Update

Alternatively, you could implement the following so that playing an audio object causes any other already playing audio to pause:

```
function stopAnyOtherCurrentlyPlayingAudio(event) {

    for(const audio of document.querySelectorAll('audio')) {

        // Only pause audio objects that are not the audio object 
        // clicked by the user
        if(audio !== event.currentTarget) {

            audio.pause()
            // audio.currentTime = 0; // Do this to reset play head,
            // simulate "stop"
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you render your audio object in the `<BottomBar />` component, just add the following `onplay` event listener:

```
render() {
    return (
        <audio controls controlsList='nodownload' autoPlay
             className='container' 

             {/* [ADD THIS] */}
             onplay={ event => stopAnyOtherCurrentlyPlayingAudio(event) }>

            <source src={this.props.songs.url} type='audio/mpeg'> 
            </source>
        </audio>
    )
}
```

Comment: That works! how would I be able to play the new song selected though?

Comment: with a button that I have